# У меня программа читает таблицу EXCEL и отправляет сообщения в ватсап и мне нужно пропустить строчки C3:C4 И E3:E4 и программа должна дальше отправлят

Tags: python, excel

У меня программа читает таблицу EXCEL и отправляет сообщения в ватсап и мне нужно пропустить строчки C3:C4 И E3:E4 и чтобы программа дальше продолжала отправлять

```
path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject7\\baza.xlsx"
vibor = input('Если хотите начать отправку сообщений прямо сейчас введите 1, если хотите 
запустит отправку по таймеру введите 2: ')
import pywhatkit
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
sheet = wb.active
def hour():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time_h = [now.strftime("%H")]
    current_time_h_int = int(current_time_h[0])
    return current_time_h_int
def min():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time_m = [now.strftime("%M")]
    current_time_m_int = int(current_time_m[0])
    return current_time_m_int + 1
if vibor == '1':
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in sheet:
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+' + str(sheet['C' + str(a)].value), sheet['E' + str(b)].value, 
hour(), min(), 15, True, 5)
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Весь вот этот кусок:

```
    a = 1
    b = 1
    for i in sheet:
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+' + str(sheet['C' + str(a)].value), sheet['E' + str(b)].value, 
hour(), min(), 15, True, 5)
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
```

Можно заменить на такое:

```
    for i,_ in enumerate(sheet, 1):
        if i in (3,4):
            continue
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+' + str(sheet['C' + str(i)].value), sheet['E' + str(i)].value, 
hour(), min(), 15, True, 5)
```

У вас вообще странно, что вы переменную цикла не используете, но я не настолько хорошо знаю работу с экселем, чтобы что-то менять в этом.

Comment: Выдает ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+' + str(sheet['C' + str(i)].value), sheet['E' + str(i)].value,hour(), min(), 15, True, 5)

Comment: Саму ошибку вы зачем отрезали

Comment: File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 307, in __getitem__
    return self._get_cell(min_row, min_col)
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 253, in _get_cell
    raise ValueError("Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576")
ValueError: Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576

Comment: А, поправил, надо с 1 считать

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!